# How to resolve the error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, model-view-controller, routes

I want to store in array, after filtering the data from in database and iterate throgh each data.

in business_cards variable stores the database data

```
 foreach($business_cards as $b) {
                    $new_arr[] = explode(',', $b->title);
                    $card[] =  $new_arr[0][0].'_'.$b->card_id; 
                    $count[] = $b->count; 
                }
```

Comment: what line does the error say is causing it?

Comment: Don't use an object as if it were an array. Presumably one of `$new_arr`, `$card`, or `$count` are an array.